# What is the technical term for when a clade on a phylogenetic tree does not have an extended branch? (see image)

Tags: bioinformatics, phylogenetics

[image]

As we see with ZCA2, ECA2 & XCA2 these branches are compressed and do not extend as TCA does. Is there a technical term for this and what usually causes it?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). For example, have you looked at the autogenerated "Related" posts associated with your question? [This post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/60841/branch-length-in-phylogenetic-trees) seems like it could be relevant. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

The phenomenon where you have different "evolutionary clocks" of selection is called `heterotachy`. The branches are therefore `heterotachic` or simply `long branches` —long branch attraction is a problem with Bayesian inference for which many arguments have been had, so there is a lot of literature on it.